# Need to change the server address of the image

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website that provides affiliate images as:

```
  <img src="http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages/0001.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages/0002.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages/0003.jpg" alt="" />, etc.
```

I want to display this image as if it was on my server.

```
  <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/0001.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/0002.jpg" alt="" />
  <img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/0003.jpg" alt="" />, etc.
```

I would prefer not to download it on the server. Server is shared so it it limited.

Any idea how that can be done?
htaccess? php? or both?:)

Example what I need is

```
    function showimage ($img)
   {   
    header ("Content-type: image/gif"); 
    $fl = file_get_contents ("$img");
    print $fl;
    }
```

only my server does not allow me that...

Comment: `str_replace("http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages", "http://www.mywebsite.com/images" , $File)` maybe ?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do, and why?  The only way to do what you want is to proxy the image, but you just said you don't want to do that.

Comment: image should be displayed from remote server but the file path in html should look as if file was on my server.

Comment: something similar to     function showimage ($img)
    {   
        header ("Content-type: image/gif"); 
        $fl = file_get_contents ("$img");
        print $fl;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $file = "page.php";
    $search = "http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages";
    $replacment = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images";

    $str = file_get_contents($file);
    $str = str_replace($search, $replacment,$str);
    file_put_contents($file, $str);

?>
```

So as an example:

`page.php` before:

```
<img src="http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages/0001.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages/0002.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.affiliatesite.com/immages/0003.jpg" alt="" />
```

`page.php` after the script:

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/0001.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/0002.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/0003.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: @SHCodeR These image tags are in a file right? If yes you can write this script change the file name and executes it! it will change all strings that matches in the file if you can write in it!

Comment: @SHCodeR You need to make your question more clear. It was noted in comments it's not clear what you're asking.